# Spring Gateway + Eureka doesnt redirect to service, 200 everytime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, gateway, service-discovery

I have a Gateway, a Eureka Server and 3 microservices.

When I try to use the gateway, I get everytime Http status 200.

When I try to send a request to a path which is not defined in the RouteLocator, I get a 404, which is good and let me know, that the route in the RouteLocator exists.

But the request doesnt gets redirected to the specified microservice.
I know this, because there are no changes in the database and nothing happens in the microservice log.

I made a route in the gateway:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
    return builder.routes()
            .route(r -> r
                    .path("/auth")
                    .filters(f->f.stripPrefix(1))
                    .uri("http://user-songsMS/")
                    .id("userModule")).build();
}
```

I also tried to configure the route in the application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway-songsMS
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: userModule
          uri: http://user-songsMS/
            - Path=/auth/**
```

This should redirect to the eureka server and the eureka server should redirect it to the user-module.
The user-module is registered in the eureka server:

[Eureka overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG3X0.png)

I also tried to change the uri in the RouteLocator to route directly to the user-module (which is on port 8083: no changes.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Spring Cloud Gateway, You are specifying the uri's as "http://user-songsMS/". They should be in the format of "lb://user-songsMS/" to go through Eureka.

Comment: That didnt work. In another method, iam calling the exchange-method from the restTemplate object, and this only works with `http://user-songsMS`, but not with `lb://...` 

Is there maybe an annotation or a configline in my application.properties which I forgot, to get things work?


I only have these lines in my application.properties for the gateway:


`spring.cloud.gateway.enabled=true`
`spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true`


And I dont have any configlines in the user-module, which are related to the gateway or the eureka service.

Comment: Of course, I enabled the clients and server with the EnableDiscoveryClient, EnableEurekaServer annotations.

Comment: I think it doesnt build the routes because I get 404 when I try to build a route with something else than /auth. And when I change /auth to something else and then request the gateway with the path /auth, I still get a 200. Maybe /auth is reserved or something.

Comment: @MarioT The gateway config needs to be lb:// to route through Eureka by service name. On the client side, you use http:// for the client side load balancer. Properties / Yaml is the better route (no pun intended) to go as you can update without rebuilding.

Answer (score -1):

I continued with other things in my project and after a while I run into several weird problems like code changes had no effects, routes were not recognized, application names were not recognized, no connection to my configserver and so on.

***The solution*** was to delete the .idea folder and copy the whole project to another place.
Than open the root project and the microservices with the .pom files.

After this i executed `mvn clean` and `mvn install` for the root project and for each microservice.

Everything works fine now.